# Add onclick method on checkbox on grid in sales order?

Tags: magento

I have added a custom column at sales_order_grid table and add this code at _prepareColumns() functions at grid.php and this checkbox is now showing but i cann't add onclick function at this column ,

```
 $this->addColumn('exported', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Exported'),
            'index' => 'exported',
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'field_name'=>'exported_',
            'values' => array(1,2),//$this->_getExported(),//
            'onclick'    => $this->getJsObjectName('addRelatedToExport'),

    ));
```

I am stuck from 4 days,Help me ,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento provides checkbox by default. you just need to have the function `_prepareMassaction` function. After including the function, include the action for `addRelatedToExport`.

Answer (score 0):

Include this function in your grid file. `Grid.php`

```
protected function _prepareMassaction(){
    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');  // code to make the checkbox related with
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('form_field_name');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('addRelatedToExport', array(
        'label'=> Mage::helper('ModuleName')->__('Add to Export'),
        'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massRelatedExport')
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

And then in the same module controller e.g `ModuleName/controllers/adminhtml/someController`

```
public function massRelatedExportAction(){
     // your code here
}
```

Comment: I want that when i click on export checbox it set/unset the value at database ,so that i need a function on checkbox like this        <input onclick="markExported(this);" type="checkbox" id="103552" checked="">

Comment: @webdeveloper  If I get your point.. you want the checkbox to trigger an action on the particular selected item **instantly**. if it so, I think it is not possible to form using magento. You need to write your own which I don't know how to do.. :(